# How would I write a transaction that would let me swap on raydium?

Tags: web3.js, send-transaction

https://solscan.io/tx/5oWH7ReHYBy3YNExFMcHCBP7a2yLdF9EXGqYSC9nPEJRsriVMFG4KKF2BGh3yD6A4MGMZ84LTyYQC5TMG7txyycn
For example, here's a transaction that is swapping on raydium, how do I write one of my own ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use use raydium SDK - https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk/blob/master/src/ammV3/ammV3.ts#L758

If you look for a optimized trading route, you can also use Jupiter SDK - https://station.jup.ag/docs/apis/swap-sdk