# How to interact with router for swap transaction?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, rust, javascript, sol

hope all doing good in your life,

How can I perform a transaction using a Solana router(like orca, Raydium) to swap Solana's native token with another token? I've come across various crates such as solana-sdk, solana-client, and solana-program,anchor-lang but I'm struggling to find a clear guide. Can you provide assistance or guidance on how to achieve this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the Raydium official documentation or the Jupiter docs for this.

1. [Raydium-Rust-Api](https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-contract-instructions)
2. [Raydium-SDK](https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk/tree/master)
3. [Jupiter](https://station.jup.ag/docs)

You can also surf through other people's questions regarding this:

1. [How to sign a Solana Raydium swap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71002378/how-to-sign-a-solana-raydium-swap)
2. [How would I write a transaction that would let me swap on raydium?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6607/how-would-i-write-a-transaction-that-would-let-me-swap-on-raydium)