# How to swap SOL <-> token / vise versa but on-chain (in a smart contract)? On Raydium or SolDex

Tags: solana-program, spl, swap, dex, raydium

I'm aware of this question [How to interact with router for swap transaction?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8058/how-to-interact-with-router-for-swap-transaction)

but mine is different.

How to swap a token for SOL or vise versa **from within** a Solana **program/smart contract**? That is, on-chain. How to interract with a router of either Raydium or SolDex? I haven't found any example of this.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V1-demo/tree/master/src) you'll find demo implementation of Raydium routing engine.
To interact directly with the routing program, you'll just need to make up your functions and plug your rpc + private key in the config files.
More details in the README.md.

The new bi-directional routing engine - available on the [beta](https://beta.raydium.io) - should get open-sourced very soon.

Link to Raydium SDK: https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk